# applescripting Displays Preference Pane

Tags: applescript

I’m attempting to write what I thought would be a simple script to change the color profile of my display.  I’ve gotten as far as bringing up the Displays pref pane and choosing the Color tab, but have then run into real problems.  My GUI scripting is sadly lacking and I cannot figure out how to choose a  display profile.   There are only two profiles showing in the scroll window ( “iMac” & “my Calibration 10-14” ).  Ideally, I would like the script to toggle between the two profiles each time it is run.  Here’s what I have so far:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
    reveal (first anchor of current pane whose name is "displaysColorTab")
end tell
```

Any help or suggestions would certainly be appreciated.  I’m running **OS 10.11.5**

Comment: Alternately have a look at [displayplacer](https://github.com/jakehilborn/displayplacer/issues) for manipulating display settings.   I like this Question and like learning new Applescript tricks but that can be a huge rabbit hole sometimes.  If you just want to set display settings displayplacer makes it easy.

Answer (score 2):

You're not that far with this good start. the script should then found which row contains the profile 1 (iMac) and which row contains the profile 2 (your profile).
if the row containing the profile 1 is selected, select the row containing profile 2.

That's what the script bellow does. You must adjust your 2 profiles in Prof1 and Prof2. the script uses "contains", so you don't have to set prof1/2 with complete value, just part of it is enough.

I also look for the case where one of the 2 profiles does not exists (then script does nothing).

```
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.displays"
reveal (first anchor of current pane whose name is "displaysColorTab")
end tell

set Prof1 to "iMac" -- define the profile 1
set Prof2 to "ACES CG Linear" -- define the profile 2
set {Row1, Row2, Sel1} to {0, 0, false} -- init values

tell application "System Events"
tell application process "System Preferences"
    tell table of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of front window
        -- search the 2 profiles in the list of rows
        repeat with I from 1 to (count of rows)
            set N to (value of static text of row I) as string
            if N contains Prof1 then
                set Row1 to I
                set Sel1 to selected of row I
            end if
            if N contains Prof2 then set Row2 to I
        end repeat
        -- make the toggle !
        if Sel1 then -- profile 1 selected, then select profile 2, if found
            if Row2 > 0 then set selected of row Row2 to true
        else -- profile 1 not yet selected, : select profile 1 if found
            if Row1 > 0 then set selected of row Row1 to true
        end if
    end tell -- table
end tell --process Sys Pref 
end tell -- System Events
```

Comment: Thanks much @pbell, unfortunately this doesn't work.  Here's what I get when running the script:  error "System Events got an error: Can’t get tab group 1 of window 1 of application process \"System Preferences\". Invalid index." number -1719 from tab group 1 of window 1 of application process "System Preferences"

Comment: it is working on my system imac27 (10.11.5). if you have same version, you should have same interface. I suspect it could be a delay of your hardware. try to add a line "delay 1" just before "set Prof1"... it will leave some time for your Mac to open the pref pane.

Comment: It's working perfectly now!  Only change I made was to add a "delay 0.5" just before the line "tell table of scroll area 1 of tab group 1 of front window"  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @Pbell where is this stuff documented?   I want to script changing the rotation and resolution of my second display.  Can't tell from above how to choose a display when there is more than one, or how to manipulate arbitrary properties.  Is this documented?  Thank you.

Comment: I am not aware of any formal Apple documentation. Using GUI scripting is not recommanded by Apple, despite it is the only way to script when Apple did not implement event handling.  Unfortunately, you must investigate yourselves to see what are the GUI objects (windows, buttons, check box, text,...) and simulate clicks. In your case, you can probably find rectangles representing your displays and their names in text boxes. To change the resolution, you must find the menu object and the relevant menu item and simulate a click in it.